# Kernel Regression with Multiple Predictors

Tags: regression, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

I know Kernel regression is a type of local regression, i.e., we consider nearby points/observations to predict the value at a particular point. In other words, we see which of the already existing predictors of other observations are near (distance wise) to the current predictor value, then take the mean value of there response values as the predicted value of current observation. This make sense, but I want to know - how kernel regression is done with multiple predictors.

1. How are weights assigned? Do we find the average distance of various predictors of a particular observation from the predictors of current observation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To smooth one typically uses a univariate kernel in each dimension of our data, and then takes a "product kernel"
    \begin{equation*}
 K_h\left( \mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}\right) =\prod_{d=1}^{q}k\left(
 \frac{x_{id}-x_{d}}{h_{d}}\right) .
 \end{equation*}
The "Nadaraya-Watson" or local-constant regression estimator then is
\begin{equation}
 \widehat E[Y|\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}]=\widehat m(\mathbf{x})=
 \frac{\frac{1}{n\left|\mathbf{h}\right|}\sum^n_{
 i=1} K_h\left(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}\right)y_i}{\frac{1}
 {n\left|\mathbf{h}\right|}\sum^n_{i=1}K_h\left(\mathbf{x}_i,
 \mathbf{x}\right)}=\sum^n_{i=1}A_i(\mathbf{x})y_i,
 \end{equation}
    where
    \begin{equation*}
 A_i(\mathbf{x})=\frac{K_h\left(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}\right)}{\sum
 ^n_{i=1}K_h\left(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}\right)}.
 \end{equation*} 
and $\left|\mathbf{h}\right|=h_1h_2\cdots h_q$, the product of the individual bandwidths.

Comment: +1. Good answer; nevertheless I think it somewhat shies away from the facts that: 1. bandwidth selection is very tricky business (especially for multi-dimensional smoothing) and this is the *real* question, 2. $n$-D surface smoothers are available and allow a natural way to account of cross-covariances between the dimensions (predictors), 3. GCV/CV are typical ways to estimate the bandwidths used. 4. Spherical smoother exists exactly so one can smooth using a single bandwidth. 5. A single bandwidth can be grossly problematic in cases where the covariates are in different scales.

Comment: The answer indeed just addresses the basics and more elaborate ones are possible!

Comment: Well, it is a good answer; I upvoted it if anything. Just I did not want a reader to have the impression that a local-constant regression from the 1960's is the (only) way to go. (I am local-linear type of person :-D )